# unescape data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, xss

So, I have data like:

```
"recipient's name"
```

That was encoded on the server as:

```
recipient&#39;s name
```

Then, I try to dynamically update a div with this text.

```
$(this).html("recipient&#39;s")
```

But I get `recipient&#39;s` name as content of the div. I would have thought that text() would have outputted the text literally, whereas html() would have converted special characters.

How can I actually get the text "recipient's name" in there? (I cannot decode the string server-side because of XSS injection)

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on, I tried this on [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ALarg/) and it worked fine under Firefox 3.6.x and Chrome 9.0.

(click on the link above and press 'run' to see it in action)